# How to avoid specifying redundant types when instantiating a generic class

Tags: c#, .net, generics, c#-4.0, interface

I have a generic interface as defined below (`IAmMeasurable`).  I have an implementation of that interface (`Sales`).  I am trying to create a generic class (`Fact`) such that I can instantiate it like so:

```
var todaySales = new Fact<Sales>();
```

Unfortunately, I am forced to do the following:

```
var todaySales = new Fact<Sales, decimal>();
```

Which seems awkward since `Sales` is defined as `IAmMeasurable<decimal>`.  The `decimal` is implied in the usage of `Sales`

```
public interface IAmMeasurable<TValue> where TValue : struct
{
}

public class Sales : IAmMeasurable<decimal>
{
}

public class Fact<TMeasure, TValue> 
    where TMeasure : IAmMeasurable<TValue> 
    where TValue : struct
{
    public TValue Observed { get; set; }
}
```

Perhaps this is just a limitation of the language?  Or is there an alternative way to structure this that to achieve my goal?  Or am I simply not thinking of the problem properly?

In my mind, there are things that are measurable and they are measured in a specific type (Sales is measured in dollars, represented as a decimal).  A fact is an observation of some measure.  I observe that today Sales is $100 (100m).

Comment: Obvioulsy `Sales : IAmMeasurable<decimal>, IAmMeasurable<int>, IAmMeasurable<double>` will confuse your `Fact` if what you looking for allowed...

Comment: ah!  I didn't realize that a class can implement the same interface twice, providing different TValues.  Is there some way to constrain that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid this, you simply need to design an intermediate class where `TValue` of `Fact` is decimal:

```
public class DecimalFact<TMeasure> : Fact<TMeasure, decimal>
    where TMeasure : IAmMeasurable<decimal>
{
}
```

Even in its 6th version, C# has no generic type parameter inference like it would happen in methods. BTW, it would be hard that a generic type parameter could be infered by usage. How would C# compiler know that `IAmMeasurable<T>` `T` generic parameter is `TValue`? Maybe some new generic constraint like `TValue is TMeasure`? Who knows ;)

It seems like above solution is the best workaround and it's the most common solution to concretize generic parameters by design.

Comment: here `TValue` is unknown in `where TMeasure : IAmMeasurable<TValue>`. change it to `IAmMeasurable<decimal>`